# How to call Java function from string stored in a Variable

Tags: java, reflection, function-call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling a method named “string” at runtime in Java and C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882948/calling-a-method-named-string-at-runtime-in-java-and-c)

I need to be able to call a function, but the function name is stored in a variable, is this possible. e.g:

```
public void foo ()
{
     //code here
}

public void bar ()
{
     //code here
}

String functionName = "foo";
```

// i need to call the function based on what is functionName

Anyhelp would be great, thanks

Comment: If you explain why you think you need to do this, we can perhaps offer alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can, using reflection. However, consider also *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 53: Prefer interfaces to reflection*. If at all possible, use interfaces instead. Reflection is rarely truly needed in general application code.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Reflection API](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/index.html)
- [Java Advanced Language Topics/Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

#### Related questions

- [Calling a method named “string” at runtime in Java and C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882948/calling-a-method-named-string-at-runtime-in-java-and-c)

Answer (score 3):

Easily done with reflection.  Some examples [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0031.html) and [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).

The main bits of code being

```
String aMethod = "myMethod";

Object iClass = thisClass.newInstance();
// get the method
Method thisMethod = thisClass.getDeclaredMethod(aMethod, params);
// call the method
thisMethod.invoke(iClass, paramsObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reflection.

Here's an [example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0031.html)

Answer (score -1):

With the [reflection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) API. Something like this:

```
    Method method = getClass().getDeclaredMethod(functionName);
    method.invoke(this);
```