# how do you bind a function in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Lets say for example we are gonna bind the function into a hashmap

```
if(identity.equals("printf")){
    doPrintf(statement);
}else if(identity.equals("scanf")){
    doScanf(statement);
}else if(identity.equals("puts")){
    doPuts(statement);
}else if (identity.equals("functioncall")){
    expectFunc  = true;
}else if (identity.equals("functioncallwithparams")){
    expectFunc  = true;
    expectParams = true;
}else if (identity.equals("assignment")){
    //doAssignment(statement);
    vartoupdate = statement;
    updateVar = true;
}else if(identity.equals("getch"))
    doGetch();
```

something like this HM.put("getch",doGetch()). How could you possibly do this?

Comment: You want to call a function whose name is based on the key?

Comment: e switch case nalang ni uyyyyyyyyyyy hahaha

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882948/calling-a-method-named-string-at-runtime-in-java-and-c Is this what you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

If I get your question correctly, you want to call a method based on its name (or at least part of it). If so, you should look at the [reflection API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/), there's a related question here on SO btw: [How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

If you can take the hit for creating a new object for each function, this can simply be achieved by creating a `Function` object for each function to be called and maintaining a mapping between the function name and it's corresponding function object.

```
public interface Function<T> {    
   public T apply(Object... vargs);    
}
```

Now just make every function object implement this interface, create new objects for each newly created class and stuff them in a map.

Answer (score 2):

```
interface Func { 
    public void exec();
}

class GetCharFunc implements Func { 
   @Override
   public void exec() { 
       // implementation details
   }
}

Func currentFunc;

if(identity.equals("getch")) {
    currentFunc = new GetCharFunc();
    myMap.put("getch", currentFunc); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it if all the functions implemented the same Interface.  Which doesn't seem to be the case for you.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support references to methods or functions as a language feature. You can either create a interface with one method and implement this multiple times with your different method invocations or use Reflection and put the `java.lang.reflect.Method` objects into your hash map.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 7, you can use a `switch` statement based on a `String` value.  Here's a brief tutorial on that:  [Use String in the switch statement with Java 7](http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/The-Switch-to-Java-7-Whats-New-with-Conditional-Switches)

If Java 7 isn't an option I think the next best option is to switch on an enum.  Here's a tutorial on [enum types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Perhaps if you explained what problem you're trying to solve you'd get better answers.