# Is it possible to postpone function call binds to runtime in Java?

Tags: java, runtime, function-calls

Consider a simple case where I ask a user to select a fruit among 10 different fruits. Say the fruits are, apples, oranges, mangoes,... etc., If the user selects apples, I call apples(), if he selects mangoes, I call mangoes() and so on...

To select which function is to be called, I DON'T want to use a switch or if-else statements. How do I select which function is to be called during run-time?

NOTE : The programming language I am using is Java

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in those methods/functions?

Comment: Create an interface fruits then each class should inherit it, then use reflection API to instantiate... Try looking for dynamic binding in Java to understand it better.

Comment: I just want to know how those methods can be called dynamically. For now, for the sake of simplicity, we can assume that I print the name of the fruit in those methods.

Comment: You need Reflection but it has pros/cons

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882948/calling-a-method-named-string-at-runtime-in-java-and-c

Comment: Thank you all! This one's an interesting concept!

Comment: @Coder.. Don't forget to accept one of the answers that you like..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use java [Refection api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to call function at runtime.

```
        Class noparams[] = {};
        Class cls = Class.forName("com.test.Fruit");
        Object obj = cls.newInstance();

        //call the printIt method
        Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("apples", noparams);
        method.invoke(obj, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Reflection`.
eg:
Write all the functions in a class ; say `com.sample.FruitStall`
Then use below code.

```
String className = "com.sample.FruitStall";
String methodName = "apple"; //here you will choose desired method
Object result;
Class<?> _class;
        try {
            _class = Class.forName(className);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            Object[] args = new Object[1];  // To Supply arguments to function
            result = _class.invokeMethod(methodName, args);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the design pattern "Command". 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186192/Command-Design-Pattern

hiding the details of the action it needs to perform.